# How do I deploy SDF files from SQL Server Compact version?

Tags: deployment, sql-server-ce

How do I deploy SDF files from `SQL Server Compact Edition`?  Do I need to install SQL Server on client machines to deploy this file?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326(VS.80).aspx

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer Any reason that wasn't in an answer so you could get votes/acceptance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
its as simple as, you can copy them to your device and use it in your application.
```